# Saving and opening a logfile

Tags: php, vb.net, logfiles, logfile

I have a vb.net app that webrequests a PHP file which does this:

```
<?php
$msg = $_GET['w'];
$logfile= 'savedrv.idps';
$fp = fopen($logfile, "w");
fwrite($fp, $msg);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I want to make a PHP file that will open the new file created "savedrv.idps" so I can read it in vb.net. This is what I tried:

```
<?php
$logfile= 'reg.idps';
$fp = fopen($logfile, "r");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You need to output, display the content. For example: `echo file_get_contents($logfile);` . Then you simply retrieve the page in your VB.NET application and parse it.

Comment: do I add the echo file_get_contents($logfile);

Comment: to where? the saveing php or the opening php or vb.net and exactly where? Thx?

Comment: oops typo I meant          thx*

Comment: Do you want to read the file in VB.NET, by making a request to a PHP page?

Comment: yes i want to read the generated file from PHP inside of VB.Net

Comment: yes i want to read the file PHP genereated in VB.NET....here is my code:   Dim code As String
        code = TextBox1.Text

     
        Dim wbClient As New System.Net.WebClient()

        Dim str As System.IO.Stream = wbClient.OpenRead("http://mysite/myfiles/reg.idps")

Comment: but vb.net cant directly read that file...it crashes and says "cannot directly remote access this file error 404"

Comment: so it needs to be converted or saved differently or use a PHP to read the file and send the text to my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your IIS settings for this Virtual Directory forbid a file with this extension to be browsed to.  I got 404.7 error attempting to open a file in IE when I browsed to the URL: `http://localhost/mysite/myvbfile.vb`  Using your browser, try to open the same URL that your VB program is attempting to access.  I anticipate that you will get the 404.7 error in the browser window too.

You have two approaches here:

1. Have your PHP script write the file to a location outside of IIS where your VB.Net program can access.
2. Modify the Request Filtering in IIS for your site so that this file can be browsed.
   [(screenshot) http://support.citrix.com/article/html/images/1CTX132655-1.gif](http://support.citrix.com/article/html/images/1CTX132655-1.gif)

Comment: the file extension is fine...it opens the file extension if its on my desktop...its because its a logfile from a PHP script that generated info....I need to make a PHP file that i can open in VB.net to read the logfile @DaveMichener

Comment: Are you saying that if you take the same file and put it on your desktop then your VB.Net application would open it fine?  If that is true, then your PHP and VB.Net apps are fine, it is a permission problem. Otherwise can you provide the logfile in question?

Comment: oh your right @DaveMichener I think i have to change the permissions in godaddy. Thx for the help!